# Compile Error with basic VBA Userform button (First VBA Project at college)

Tags: excel, vba

For a Spreadsheet task set by college, I have been asked to include a VBA user form into a student database spreadsheet. I have written a sub routine which enters the new student into a specific line within the worksheet (AddStudent) is there any obvious reason why Vba is not processing this function properly. The lines below show the code I have used.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.txtStudent.Value = "" Or Me.txtBirth.Value = "" Or Me.txtFirstAdd.Value = "" Or Me.txtSecondAdd.Value = "" Or Me.txtTown.Value = "" Or Me.txtCounty = "" Or Me.txtPost.Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please fill in all details"
Else
Call AddStudent
End If
End Sub
```

This is my first VBA task and I am no programmer, so I apologise for what might appear to be a trivial question.(also I am  having a little trouble with formatting as this is my first post of stack overflow)

When The Button is pressed I receive the following error message "compile error; Else without IF"

Thank you to anyone who may have the time to help me out here.

Comment: Select the code text and press the button that looks like two curly brackets, this will format it as code. Alternatively, ensure that each line begins with at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `MsgBox` statement on a new line:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.txtStudent.Value = "" Or Me.txtBirth.Value = "" Or Me.txtFirstAdd.Value = "" Or Me.txtSecondAdd.Value = "" Or Me.txtTown.Value = "" Or Me.txtCounty = "" Or Me.txtPost.Value = "" Then 
    MsgBox "Please fill in all details"
Else
    Call AddStudent
End If
End Sub
```

The reasoning: VBA allows you to do `If {condition} Then {Action}` as a single statement, but when you construct your code this way, you can't have an `Else` clause. It's basically a way to shorthand:

```
If {condition} Then
   {Action}
Else
    'Do Nothing
End If
```

Also, if you have several `OR` conditions, you can improve legibility with a `Case` statement instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case ""
        Case Me.txtStudent.Value, Me.txtBirth.Value, Me.txtFirstAdd.Value, Me.txtSecondAdd.Value, Me.txtTown.Value, Me.txtCounty, Me.txtPost.Value
            MsgBox "Please fill in all details"
        Case Else
            Call AddStudent
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Just want to say a big thank you. I really appreciate your quick response and additional explanations. The code is now working as desired. Now to improve on my formatting :) thanks again!